# Cyclic reference in java

Tags: java

If class A has a reference of class B and class B has a reference of class A, is it acceptable in Java? If yes, When we execute class A by the time class B will not be instantiated. So how the compiler will execute the reference of class B?

TIA

Comment: Are you sure you mean that the classes have the references? Do you mean that an object of class `A` has a reference to an object of class `B`?

Comment: Have you tried this? That would probably take less than asking the question here.

Comment: Instead of describing the code, write it, test it, and post it if you don't understand how it works.

Comment: You are confusing runtime with compile-time and frankly, I don't know which you are in fact asking about. A piece of code would have helped (but then, you would already know the answer).

Comment: question need more clarity . all classes directly or indirect extend Object class and i can pass Object obj as a variable to that class . eg . class Xyz extends Object { Object obj; .... }

Answer (score 8):

> If class A has a reference of class B and class B has a reference of class A, is it acceptable in Java?

Yes.

> When we execute class A by the time class B will not be instantiated. So how the compiler will execute the reference of class B?

You have to create the cyclic reference by creating one object first, and then the other, and then closing the cycle; e.g. something like this.

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B(a);
a.setB(b);
```

(This assumes that the `A` class has been defined with a `setB(A)` method.  There are other ways to form the cycle too, but this is the simplest.)

---

But note that your terminology is all completely wrong.

- You don't "execute" a class.  You *instantiate* or *create an instance of* a class.
- The compiler (for example `javac`) doesn't "execute" anything ... it just *compiles* code.
- The thing that *executes* (i.e *runs*) Java code is a Java Virtual Machine; e.g. when you use the `java` command.

(It is important that you learn and use the correct Java terminology if you are going to communicate with other IT professionals.  It avoids a lot of miscommunication and confusion!)

Comment: You can actually leak `this` out of A's constructor: `new B(this)`. In practice this happens a lot in (badly written) GUI code.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - That is true (if I correctly understand what you mean) ... but I'm trying to keep it simple.

Comment: It's also a malpractice, so you're keeping it clean at the same time :)

Comment: This may "work" form the java perspective, but I've found that circular references can come with a cost.    

For example, I know for darn sure that in the IntelliJ Java debugger when you "inspect" a class that participates in a circular reference, the debugger pauses a good long while before displaying the value.     I think it could probably do better than that, but... it seems NOT to.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly fine.

Object A can reference Object B, and object B can reference Object A. You actually see this in graphs in code frequently where a node will reference an entire graph, while the graph references many nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is acceptable, in as much as the compiler stores calls to the other class as method name plus signature: parameter types, again as text.

I have even seen following horror

```
interface A {
    final A = new B();
}

class B implements A {
}
```

Java is loosely bound; there are corresponding runtime exceptions thrown.
The same is compiling against another version of a library jar, and running with a jar with broken API.